# SQL statement in php variable?

Tags: php, mysqli

Ok so I realized this probably looks crazy to good programers but I'm a noob and just trying to figure out the basics.  I'm trying to build a simple question/answer site.  I can submit a question to the db just fine but when I direct a user to answer I need to put the correct question id (q_id) as it's a foreign key in my answers table.  I cant find anything online to solve this problem.  I'm sure I'll get "dont use mysqli_query" or something but if anyone can just help me understand how to get the correct value passed into q_id it would be a great help.  Seeing my php code below it will probably make sense what I'm attempting to do:

```
//set up connection credentials
$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "root";
$password = ""; 
$dbname = "ask";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
//gather the data from the form
$answer = $_POST["answer"];
$q_id = mysqli_query($conn,"select q_id from questions order by q_id 
desc limit 1");


 $sql = "INSERT INTO answers (answer, q_id)  VALUES ('$answer', 
  '$q_id')";
 if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {

 echo "answer submitted";




} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);}



?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open the page that display question, you already use the q_id, just use it again.

Like the stackoverflow URL, question ID is on the URL:
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44896448/sql-statement-in-php-variable`

Because you do not know re-write yet so you can use $_GET method to get q_id.

EDITED:

User insert_id; to get last id after question submitted then you got the id for the question

```
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
 $last_id = $conn->insert_id;
 echo "answer submitted, id is ".$last_id;




} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);}



?>
```

Comment: ahh I did not think about $_GET  I will try this.  Thank you!

Comment: Question:  So how to I pass the user ID (q_id in my case) to the url?  I'm able to have the form submit a question and the get method posts it in url but the ID is not in the url?  I have it set up in my DB as auto increment and when I have the user input the question it goes to my DB but the ID is only in DB not in url?

Comment: This is great thank you.  I'm getting closer and closer to a solution.